# ls: cannot access 'PATH=./': No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, exec

I'm new to using linux and the bash command line but I was trying to see whether I could execute basic bash commands (or program) from a c file. My code is really simple and I could've sworn that it was working but suddenly it is not acknowledging that the path even exists.

```
char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l"};
char* environ[] = {"PATH=./", (char*)0};
execve("/bin/ls", arg, environ);/*execute the command 'ls -l' in curdir*/
```

I've tried to set as `PATH=/bin` but it's not even executing the command in that directory. it just returns a similar error.

NOTE: I have tried

```
char* environ[] = {"PATH=./", NULL};
```

I've even tried using the `envp` from main() and that STILL doesn't work.

Comment: You need a NULL value at the end of the arg list.

Comment: @dbush ```char* environ[] = {"PATH=./", NULL};``` I've tried this and it doesn't work either

Comment: @Lezcer change `char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l"};` to `char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};`

Comment: *What* error is it reporting?

Comment: @chepner, I think the error reported is given in this question's title.

Comment: @dbush i see what you mean. thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message ...

> ```
> ls: cannot access 'PATH=./': No such file or directory
> ```

... indicates that the `ls` utility is attempting to access a file named "PATH=./", which it does not find.  That is a manifestation of the undefined behavior arising from your code ...

> ```
> char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l"};
> char* environ[] = {"PATH=./", (char*)0};
> execve("/bin/ls", arg, environ);/*execute the command 'ls -l' in curdir*/
> ```

... on account of `execve()` expecting and relying upon the argument list to which `arg` points being terminated by a null pointer.

Although it is somewhat fraught to try to rationalize or interpret undefined behavior, you can imagine that the contents of arrays `arg` and `environ` are laid out one immediately after the other in memory, so that the combined representation of these two is the same as the representation of a four-element array of `char *`.  This view is perhaps useful for understanding why the `arg` and `env` arrays must be terminated by null pointers in the first place.

The fix is to append a null pointer to the value of `arg`:

```
char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
```

Note also that in this particular case there is no apparent advantage to specifying an environment, so you could simplify by using `execv()` instead.

Note, too, that path elements other than `/` itself should not contain a trailing `/` character. This is not part of a correct name for a directory, and although you can often get away with it, it is poor form.

Answer (score 3):

Put NULL in the end of arg array.

```
char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
```

The NULL is used to mark the end of the array.

Comment: More explanation: without the `NULL`, `execve` is effectively concatenating the two arrays, because it doesn't know to stop reading from memory. It sees `ls`, it sees `-l`, then it sees `PATH=/bin`, and *then* it sees the `NULL`. (Undefined behavior, but in practice the two arrays are being allocated in adjacent memory cells.)

Answer (score 1):

Please always post a complete program.

As said in the man page, and as said in the comments above, you need a `NULL` at the end of the arguments list.

You do not need to pass anything in `envp[]` since you are running just `ls`

By convention you should pass the full path of the executable in `argv[0]`

In short, this works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* arg[] = { "/bin/ls", "-l", NULL };
    execve("/bin/ls", arg, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```